# system verilog randc behavior when constraint condition changes

Tags: random, system-verilog

I read that the permutation sequence of randc variable changes when the constraint on the variable changes. But considering the below example, where the constraint is not re-defined but the condition (y) changes - is there a chance that the permutation sequence of randc variable is recomputed ?

```
randc bit [5:0] x;
rand bit y;                                                                                                                                                         

constraint  c_x {
    (y)  -> {x inside {[10:13]}};
    (!y) -> {x inside {[20:23]}};
}
```

I tested it and even though 'y' changes for every randomize() call - the permutation seq of x is not changing. Just wanted to understand this finer detail of randc.

Comment: I was expecting the permutation seq will regenerate when 'y' changes. But it is not - so I am trying to understand the behavior clearly. Below answer makes it clear for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have only one constraint expression and all variables are random. The permutation sequence of a `randc` variable get reset on

- construction of the object
- change of a variable's rand_mode()
- change of a constraint's constraint_mode()
- change of a non-rand variable's value used in a constraint expression
- call randomize using a different `with {}` clause
- no remaining values in the permutation

There must be a dependency on the randc variable for any of the above changes to have an effect.

Comment: I think it also resets  - when constraint of randc variable changes (e.g. obj.randomize() **with {}** ). Is it covered under your "construction of the object" case ?